# Google marker is not showing up on google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to learn google map, setting a static location in google map in fragment using tab where I can see a map and Location printing in log but marker is not showing. I have used `visible(true)` in marker too but its not working. Here is my code

```
    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gMap) {
            googleMap = gMap;
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            try {
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } catch (SecurityException se) {
                Toast.makeText(self, "wdwdwqwdwdd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //Edit the following as per you needs
            googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);


            // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(SYDNEY).visible(true).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PERTH).visible(true).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(BRISBANE).visible(true).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
            Log.i("lkfjdjdvdsvf", String.valueOf(SYDNEY));
            Log.i("lkfjdjdwdwdwdvdsvf", String.valueOf(PERTH));
            Log.i("lkfjdjdcacsacvdsvf", String.valueOf(BRISBANE));




            // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(SYDNEY).zoom(12).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


        }
    });




    return view;

}
```

Comment: private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);

Comment: are you calling map.clear() from anywhere else in your code?

Comment: no didn't use it

Comment: try implementing OnMapReadyCallback to your activity instead of doing this inside any method.

Comment: ill try that too its not working

Comment: Can you show us the xml also

Comment: Do you see your markers if you remove `.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker))`?